# Dataweave - Comparing a timestamp if it's between an interval

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

I want to verify if a timestamp ex. "22-07-15T16:00:00" is smaller than  "22-07-15T23:00:00" and bigger than "22-07-15T16:00:00"

```
((now() as String {format:"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"}) >= (now() as String {format: "yy/MM/dd"} ++ "T16:00:00")) and < (now() as String {format: "yy/MM/dd"} ++ "T23:00:00")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just compare using basic logical operator like `<, >, <=, >=` on `Date`, `DateTime` and `LocalDateTime` for comparison.
`t1 > t2` will return true if t1 comes after t2. So you can use

```js
%dw 2.0
var toCheck = "22-07-15T16:00:00" as LocalDateTime {format:"yy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"}
var t1 = "22-07-15T23:00:00" as LocalDateTime {format:"yy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"}
var t2 = "22-07-15T16:00:00" as LocalDateTime {format:"yy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"}
output application/json
---
(toCheck < t1) and (toCheck > t2)
```